# Grid Transform like photoshop

Tags: bezier-curves

I want to transform 3d objects like grid transformation in photoshop. I have some meshes that I would like to give them curves and shape them into place. I could do this in photoshop by using grid transform, but I cannot find something similar in blender, only complicated procedures that need days of work to do what grid transform in photoshop can do in seconds..

Is there something similar in blender? Is there an easy way to transform meshes and give them curves?

Comment: Could you share an example of the things that you want to accomplish, your are comparing two diferent apps, Blender has a lot of ways to do things, so, a better description could be a good way to start. with that said, globally speaking, Lattice modifier is like a 3D Grid Transform

Comment: I would say that the closest thing to what you mean is a Lattice in 3D space. You cant really compare a grid transformation as it is a 2D space work that works with much less data. May be show us what are you trying do achive.

Comment: I agree that the lattice modifier is the best candidate. Keep the divisions at 2 and you only have 4 handles to tweak your object. You can even rotate in 3D and scale.